# HAXM Installation failure in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intel, haxm, avd-manager

I am trying to download HAXM to run devices on Android Studio but I keep getting a failure message and none of the suggestions from similar questions is working either. Whelp

'silent_install.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Intel® HAXM installation failed. To install Intel® HAXM follow the instructions found at: https://github.com/intel/haxm/wiki/Installation-Instructions-on-Windows

*the device I'm running is an HP with Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz   2.81 GHz

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by enabling 'Virtualization' in BIOS.

p.s. you will need to restart then press either esc/f10 when windows screen shows up to do that ;)